# Closing the project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

We have multiple small projects within our organization. Ever since we adopted Azure DevOps recently, we started creating the individual Azure DevOps projects for everyone of these projects. The ALM process has been going on very well, with end to end traceability established with in the online tool.

However, as we get to end of each of these projects, we started to realize that these individual project and its code needs to be maintained further for the bug fixes and hotfixes. Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't give a clear road-map for a project code, once it is completed.

Since we have a separate devops project for all the maintenance applications, this becomes much more confusing.

So, Could you suggest me on what is the best practice to maintain the code after the project is completed? Here are some options that I can think of.

1. Just keep the code in the same project and keep doing the bug fixes there. But, this will create an administrative nightmare to keep track of multiple projects for our maintenance application landscape (especially, since we already have a single projects with multiple repos and teams maintained).
2. Migrate the code from the completed project repository to the maintenance project. But, this again is a migration from one repo to another. So, I am not sure if this is right.

Comment: What kind of repo is it? One advantage of the distributed nature of git is that migrating repos is less of a hassle...

Comment: More generally, what are your criteria? Once you write those out, the decision will probably be much clearer. That's more a question of business priorities and organisational details, not something the general public can help with here on SO

Comment: Well, you can leave project where they are and create the maintenance project. You will track there issues and mark issue with a tag per project to indicate which areas are involved by given issue. Try something first and then try to tailor to your needs. IMHO no point for big migration right now and it will even introduce more bad than good.

Comment: The work items on the Boards are meant to keep track of bugs and other work that's yet to be done. Using the Pull Requests feature somebody can request to have their commits added the `master` branch and attach the related work items to it.